# Angular how to fire a callback function after DOM elements are updated for each digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make an angular body-scroll only table. To make it simpler, I created two tables, one of which only has the headers, and the other table is for the body. The body table is wrapped into a div with `max-height:300px`.

The two tables are aligned when the body table does not have a scroll bar, but disaligned when the body table has a scroll bar. What I tried is to watch the clientWidth of the body table, whenever it changes, apply the new client width to the header table so that those two tables are always aligned.

In the controller, I have

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    var tbody = $element.find('tbody.sku-table-body');
    return tbody[0].clientWidth;

}, function(newClientWidth) {
    console.log(newClientWidth);
    $scope.tableClientWidth = newClientWidth;
});
```

And then in the header table, add `ng-style="{'width': tableClientWidth}"`

The issues is the watch callback is called before angular update the DOM. 
For example, if initially there are only 10 rows in the table, and there is no scroll bar. The two tables are aligned. Then I clicked a button to load 10 more records, the scroll bar on the body table appears, but the newClientWidth is still the old client width since the watch callback is called before angular update the body table. The two tables are disaligned now.

What I need is fire a function to update the header table width whenever angular finishes updating the DOM for each digest cycle. The function may be something like

`function(){ 
    var clientWidth= $('.body-table')[0].clientWidth;
    $('.header-table').width(clientWidth); 
}`

I have seen $evalAsync and $timeout, and looks like they are one time execution. What I want is fire a function EACH time AFTER angular finishes updating the DOM.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your only option is to combine `$watch` with `$evalAsync` and manually track last width, compare it with current and synchronize if it differs. Check out [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbNQNw).